# How multiple load balancers work

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability, high-load

Assume we face `x` requests per seconds, where `x` is magic number of requests which single load balancer cannot handle.

So we have to use multiple load balancers to handle all requests, yes? But how? I need to load balance the load balancers farm? Poor idea, at the end it also occurs that single load balancer must handle all requests.

So how to use multiple load balancers to handle enormous number of requests?

Comment: There are other load balancing solutions than dedicated load balancers which cannot be cascaded. However your question is quite unclear and needs further details.

Comment: You can utilize Equal-cost multi-path routing (ECMP) to send traffic to multiple load balancers. See for example [booking.com load balancing architecture](https://www.haproxy.com/user-spotlight-series/scaling-the-edge-how-booking-com-powers-a-global-application-delivery-network-with-haproxy) and [github architecture](https://www.haproxy.com/user-spotlight-series/inside-the-github-load-balancer)

Comment: Your false assumption seems to be that all traffic, all requests must first reach a single destination before requests can be distributed evenly (by a loadbalancer).  That isn't the case in properly designed solution. You can leverage  for example the DNS  layer to ensure that  the visitors to `www.example.com` will see different IP-address based on their geographic location. And a smart DNS will ensure that vistors from a specific will will be directed to the `www.example.com` instance hosted behind nearby IP-address X while other vistors will see IP-address Y for `www.example.com`.

Comment: Many other techniques, based on for example routing will do the same: ensure that all traffic does not end up in a single destination. Of course  that takes a properly decentralised application design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing all the traffic through a single load balancer you can load balance on the network level utilizing [Equal-cost multi-path routing (ECMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-cost_multi-path_routing).

There are two presentations from HAProxy Conf 2019 which describe load balancing architecture of [Booking.com](https://www.haproxy.com/user-spotlight-series/scaling-the-edge-how-booking-com-powers-a-global-application-delivery-network-with-haproxy) and [GitHub](https://www.haproxy.com/user-spotlight-series/inside-the-github-load-balancer)

[image: Booking.com ECMP architecture]

[image: GitHub GLB]

Comment: or just use rrDNS

Comment: @symcbean round-robin DNS isn't very good for HA.

Comment: Perhaps, but installing an BigIp f5 on the local network of everyone who might visit your site is a little expensive. Also ECMP becomes very difficult to implement across multiple sites/multiple proviers.

Comment: ....and I wouldn't expect someone operating on the scale of booking.com or github to base their planning of a new infrastructure solely on discussion like this.